# SSIS - Update source records after transfer

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssis

I have 2 SQL Servers.
ServerA and ServerB

They both have a table called "OrderRequest"

ServerA is "in house" and ServerB is in our datacenter.

ServerA has a linked server - ServerB
On ServerB there is a linked server back to ServerA

I need to remove the latter linked server, as the firewall that allows ServerB to "see" ServerA is changing, and won't allow this any more.

We have a SSIS package that copies data from our datacenter (ServerB) to our in-house Server (ServerA)

At the moment, the SQL statement is along the lines of:

```
SELECT *
FROM ServerB.OrderRequest
WHERE
OrderID NOT In (SELECT OrderID FROM ServerA.OrderRequest)
```

As you can see, this will require ServerB to be able to “see” ServerA

What I want to do is something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM ServerB.OrderRequest
WHERE
Transferred = 0
```

This is easy enough to do. However, in my SSIS I have a Union (as I have more than one WebDB)
After that, they are inserted into ServerA.

What I’d need to do, is set Transferred to true, on successful insert.
How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are obviously many ways to do this, but it depends on a few factors (for instance, are you inserting more records into ServerB as you are doing the transfer?)

- Do a multicast to a foreach container
  with an OLE DB command inside. Call
  update on each record on ServerB.
- Start a transaction before you select. After the select is complete, update all rows to transferred (if you want even more atomicity, select into a temp table to ensure you're updating correctly). Once complete: commit. Fail: rollback.
- Simply run a SQL Command on completion: UPDATE ServerB.OrderRequest SET Transferred = 1 WHERE Transferred = 0

Comment: thanks, after some more googling, i think the foreach container is the way forward... any idea how to do it? I've added another Q on this subject - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614518/ssis-using-a-foreach-loop-container-to-update-records-after-transfer