# Opening Excel files from SSIS package

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

How many excel files can an SSIS package able to open and insert if the data in my excel files are less than 500KB?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/3a1fc765-9b2d-43fd-86d3-9d979827f3a6) it was tested for XML connection test - there is no known limitation. In other word, limitation depends from computer resources.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `500 KB` files can be easily handled by SSIS packages if the machine running the packages meets the [**minimum requirements**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms143506%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) listed by Microsoft.

Please take a look at my answer in [**this link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061075/sql-integration-services-to-load-tab-delimited-file/6159600#6159600). In the link, tab delimited files are being loaded into SQL using SSIS. The `.txt` files used in the example were of size **41 MB** containing a million rows. Configuration of the machine used for testing is provided in the answer. That should hopefully give an idea about SSIS capabilities of handling large files.

Hope that helps.