# SSIS Join Recordset With Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, ssis-2008

I have an SSIS package in which I'm reading the records from a Flat File and storing them in a recordset. Is it possible to compare the values in the recordset with the values in a database table and update the table?

I'm Using SQL Server 2008 R2 and Same version of SSIS.

Comment: Use a lookup to match identical IDs, When match then use OLE DB SQL Command to update your affteced rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leran2002's answer in general is right, the most straight forward way is to have a lookup component set up to Redirect rows to no match output and use a destination and a OLE DB Command afterwards.

However depending on the size of the result sets, this might be slow, since the lookup component will check each row one-by-one and if your destination table has lots of records, this will take some time. Furthermore, depending on your cache settings in the lookup component, it can use lots of memory.

There are two more ways to achieve this:

**Merge Join**

Using your file source and your destination table as a source, you can use a Merge Join. The logic in the DFT is a bit more complex, but this more a set-based approach and with large result sets it is working better.

You'll have to implement the logic which record has to be updated, inserted, deleted or discarded from the file using a conditional split component.

I highly recommend this question (not exactly your problem, but a good comparison in my opinion): [What are the differences between Merge Join and Lookup transformations in SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735733/what-are-the-differences-between-merge-join-and-lookup-transformations-in-ssis)

**Staging table**

Another way is to use a staging table to temporarily store the records from a file. In this case, your DFT just loads the records from a file into the staging table, then with one or more `Execute SQL Task` you can do the merging of the two data sets. (UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, MERGE, you can use what fits your needs).

Answer (score 0):

Usualy I use `Lookup`-component with option `Redirect rows to no match output`.
And after that you can use two rowsets which named `Lookup No Match Output` and `Lookup Match Output`.

PS. I have three articles about SSIS, but they in Russian (but there is a lot of SQL-scripts and pictures).
If it's interesting you, you can look the following link - https://habrahabr.ru/post/330618/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I really appreciate your time. Let me try this one and I will get back to you.